# databinding a Dataset to a listbox...Datatemplate needs to display from multiple columns

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, dataset

I was trying to figure this out for quite some time.I want a Databind a listbox with a Dataset.Simple as it can get.But my problem is that i want my datatemplate to display Columns from two tables,in the dataset.I have tried many samles..but everything i found just gives the dataset as datacontext and gives a single table as itemsource.But my condition is that i want more than one table in my datatemplate..

For eg:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="EmployeeDataTemplate">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
      <Image Source="{Binding Path=Mast/Image}" Stretch="Fill" Width="50" Height="50" />
   </Border>
   <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" >
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Mast/Firstname}" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Mast/Lastname}" Padding="3,0,0,0"/>
      </StackPanel>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Details/Age}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Details/Role}" />
   </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Any way to do this..? I am confused...!

I tried giving the Dataset as datacontext and Itemsource as {Binding} But only one row is displayed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a view model class that exposes three properties:

1. `MasterTable` of type `IEnumerable<MasterTableRow>`
2. `SelectedMaster` of type `DataRowView`
3. `MasterDetails` of type `IEnumerable<DetailsTableRow>`

In your view model, put your instance of your `DataSet`, and return the appropriate values for the properties. To wrap it all up, you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and fire change notifications for `SelectedMaster` and `MasterDetails` whenever `SelectedMaster` changes.

Remember to set the view model as the `DataContext` for the bindings.

Here's how it might look like:

```
public partial class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DataSet1 ds;
    DataRowView selectedMaster;

    public IEnumerable<DataSet1.MasterTableRow> MasterTable
    {
        get { return ds.MasterTable; }
    }

    public DataRowView SelectedMaster
    {
        get { return selectedMaster; }
        set
        {
            if (selectedMaster != value)
            {
                selectedMaster = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MasterDetails");
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedMaster");
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<DataSet1.DetailsTableRow> MasterDetails
    {
        get
        {
            var masterRow = (DataSet1.MasterTableRow)SelectedMaster.Row;
            return masterRow.GetDetailsTableRows();
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

In XAML, the bindings might look like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MasterTable}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMaster}" 
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MasterTemplate}"/>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MasterDetails}" 
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DetailsTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: thanks Aviad...I tried to do the same but i have some doubts.FIrst of all,i cant do this on a normal dataset right..? I guess i have to use a strogly typed datset..for eg an XSD instance.I tried to implement this with an xsd but i cant get through and i got some errors..In 
return masterRow.GetDetailsTableRows();
I am getting error becasue GetDetailsTableRows() cannot be found.Am i doing things right..? Can i have a working sample..? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Yes my example used a strongly typed dataset with a `MasterTable` and a `DetailsTable` you can modify the above sample to use a regular (non typed) dataset, by using `GetChildRows` and passing the relation.